# Cannot convert type User to AccountModel

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a Web API using this tutorial [here](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/26/aspnet-core-21-simple-api-for-authentication-registration-and-user-management#user-dto-cs). However, I have create the User.cs and AccountModel.cs like the one in the tutorial, but I am getting an error when returning user in Login function in AuthRepository.cs. Am I missing something or is there something I am doing wrong?

> Cannot convert type User to AccountModel

**User.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UserWebAPI.Entities
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**AccountModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace UserWebAPI.Models
{
    public class AccountModel //Dto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**AuthRepository.cs**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UserWebAPI.Models;

namespace UserWebAPI.Data
{
    public class AuthRepository : IAuthRepository
    {
        private DataContext _context;

        public AuthRepository(DataContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public AccountModel Login(string username, string password)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                return null;

            var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == username);

            if (user == null)
                return null;

            if (!VerifyPasswordHash(password, user.PasswordHash, user.PasswordSalt))
                return null;

            return user;
        }

        private static bool VerifyPasswordHash(string password, byte[] storedHash, byte[] storedSalt)
        {
            if (password == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password)) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be empty or whitespace only string.", "password");
            if (storedHash.Length != 64) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid length of password hash (64 bytes expected).", "passwordHash");
            if (storedSalt.Length != 128) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid length of password salt (128 bytes expected).", "passwordHash");

            using (var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512(storedSalt))
            {
                var computedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
                for (int i = 0; i < computedHash.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (computedHash[i] != storedHash[i]) return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably `_context.Users` doesn't return an `IQueryable<AccountModel>`

Comment: I changed `public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }` to `public DbSet<AccountModel> Users { get; set; }` and it will return user now, but AccountModel does not have PasswordHash and PasswordSalt but User.cs does, so it looks like I have to find another solution to verify password hash.

Comment: A little off topic, but you may want to reconsider the use of HMACSHA512 as your password hash. One of the characteristics of a good password hashing algorithm is configurable slowness (which HMACSHA512 lacks), and there are other superior alternatives such as PBKDF2 and bCrypt. See: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/16817

Answer (score 1):

According to the method definition, Login returns AccountModel. However, you are returning an User object, not an AccountModel object. Even if AccountModel and User have the exact same properties, they are different classes and are therefore not interchangable.

To make it work, you could map the User object to an AccountModel object (manually, or through a library like [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/))

You could also have AccountModel and User inherit from a common interface, and have Login return that interface instead.

Comment: Yes I have automapper configured, but the problem is AccountModel does not have passwordhash and password salt, I will try to find a way to fix it.

Comment: @AlejandroH, even if you have automapper configured, you are not actually doing any mapping in the code you provided.

For example, after you do VerifyPasswordHash, you could do this in your return statement: `return  Mapper.Map<User, AccountModel>(user);`

Answer (score 0):

[ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Object_MemberwiseClone)

with Object.MemberwiseClone Method and following way:

```
using System;

    public class IdInfo
    {
        public int IdNumber;

        public IdInfo(int IdNumber)
        {
            this.IdNumber = IdNumber;
        }
    }

    public class Person 
    {
        public int Age;
        public string Name;
        public IdInfo IdInfo;

        public Person ShallowCopy()
        {
           return (Person) this.MemberwiseClone();
        }

        public Person DeepCopy()
        {
           Person other = (Person) this.MemberwiseClone();
           other.IdInfo = new IdInfo(IdInfo.IdNumber);
           other.Name = String.Copy(Name);
           return other;
        }
    }

    public class Example
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // Create an instance of Person and assign values to its fields.
            Person p1 = new Person();
            p1.Age = 42;
            p1.Name = "Sam";
            p1.IdInfo = new IdInfo(6565);

            // Perform a shallow copy of p1 and assign it to p2.
            Person p2 = p1.ShallowCopy();

            // Display values of p1, p2
            Console.WriteLine("Original values of p1 and p2:");
            Console.WriteLine("   p1 instance values: ");
            DisplayValues(p1);
            Console.WriteLine("   p2 instance values:");
            DisplayValues(p2);

            // Change the value of p1 properties and display the values of p1 and p2.
            p1.Age = 32;
            p1.Name = "Frank";
            p1.IdInfo.IdNumber = 7878;
            Console.WriteLine("\nValues of p1 and p2 after changes to p1:");
            Console.WriteLine("   p1 instance values: ");
            DisplayValues(p1);
            Console.WriteLine("   p2 instance values:");
            DisplayValues(p2);

            // Make a deep copy of p1 and assign it to p3.
            Person p3 = p1.DeepCopy();
            // Change the members of the p1 class to new values to show the deep copy.
            p1.Name = "George";
            p1.Age = 39;
            p1.IdInfo.IdNumber = 8641;
            Console.WriteLine("\nValues of p1 and p3 after changes to p1:");
            Console.WriteLine("   p1 instance values: ");
            DisplayValues(p1);
            Console.WriteLine("   p3 instance values:");
            DisplayValues(p3);
        }

        public static void DisplayValues(Person p)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("      Name: {0:s}, Age: {1:d}", p.Name, p.Age);
            Console.WriteLine("      Value: {0:d}", p.IdInfo.IdNumber);
        }
    }
```

output

```
// The example displays the following output:
//       Original values of p1 and p2:
//          p1 instance values:
//             Name: Sam, Age: 42
//             Value: 6565
//          p2 instance values:
//             Name: Sam, Age: 42
//             Value: 6565
//       
//       Values of p1 and p2 after changes to p1:
//          p1 instance values:
//             Name: Frank, Age: 32
//             Value: 7878
//          p2 instance values:
//             Name: Sam, Age: 42
//             Value: 7878
//       
//       Values of p1 and p3 after changes to p1:
//          p1 instance values:
//             Name: George, Age: 39
//             Value: 8641
//          p3 instance values:
//             Name: Frank, Age: 32
//             Value: 7878
```